# Hydra on Windows comes up with "[ERROR] Compiled without LIBSSH v0.4.x support, module is not available"

Tags: windows, libssh, hydra

After trying to run the following query with THC-HYDRA:

```
hydra -l ROOT -P pass.lst -M hosts.lst ssh
```

I get this responce:

```
Hydra v7.5 (c)2013 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - for legal purposes only

Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2013-11-15 16:35:56
[ERROR] Compiled without LIBSSH v0.4.x support, module is not available!
```

I downloaded LIBSSH from libssh.org and installed it to no avail. The internet seems to hold no answers however I can see others have asked the same question.

Thanks very much indeed,
user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I compiled and then realized I forgot libssh when I tried to run it against my router so I installed it and recompiled; still it was not working. 
I tried "make clean" and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get purge hydra
apt-get install cmake libssl-dev

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://www.libssh.org/files/0.4/libssh-0.4.8.tar.gz
tar zxf libssh-0.4.8.tar.gz
cd libssh-0.4.8
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DWITH_SSH1=ON ..
make
make install

cd /usr/local/src
wget http://freeworld.thc.org/releases/hydra-6.3-src.tar.gz
tar zxf hydra-6.3-src.tar.gz
cd hydra-6.3-src
./configure
make
make install
```